# calling a javascript function within markup created by javascript using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have form fields which are displayed using Jquery on click of a button.

```
[select dropdown: conOperator]   [textfield: conValue ]  [select dropdown: conValuedd]
```

conValuedd is hidden by default.

I'm trying to figure out a way so that when I select either Apple or Banana in the first select drop down [conOperator], it hides the textfield conValue and displays drop down conValuedd instead. However, if I were to select Watermelon, it would display conValue and hide conValuedd again. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

```
$('<select id="conOperator' + num + '" name="conOperator' + num + '" class="standard_select" style="width:147px;">
    <option>Watermelon</option>
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
   </select>&nbsp;
   <input type="text" id="conValue' + num + '" name="conValue' + num + '" class="short_input" value="" style="width:147px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <select style="display:none" id="conValuedd' + num +'" multiple="multiple" size="5">
    <option value="option1">Blah</option>
    <option value="option2">Blah</option>
   </select>').appendTo('#addCondition');
```

Comment: _altogether now..._  **what have you tried?**

Comment: Completely unrelated, it's somewhat of a bad practice to use hardcoded string values in your code, you might want to consider using a templating library like hogan.js to generate that markup. Unless of course this is purely for testing purposes in which case the overhead of doing so might not be worth the flexibility you gain.

Comment: Your jQuery code looks like you're doing it wrong. @Radu is correct - a templating engine might be the right thing, or you could simply use jQuery's `.clone()` to duplicate an exsisting HTML structure. Building HTML from huge JavaScript strings is… sub-optimal.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like a:

```
$('#addCondition').on('change','#conOperator' + num, function(e){        
    switch( $('option:checked',this).text() ){
        case 'Apple':
        case 'Banana':
            $(this).nextAll(':text:first').hide();
            $(this).nextAll('select:first').show();
            break;
        case 'Watermelon':
            $(this).nextAll(':text:first').show();
            $(this).nextAll('select:first').hide();
            break;
    }
});
$('#conOperator' + num).trigger('change');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/E76sS/)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `appendTo()`, the generated `<select/>` is added to the DOM so you can retrieve it with jQuery and add a listener on it.

```
$("#conOperator" + num).change(function() {
    // Your logic here
}
```